# How to create pandas DataFrame with index from the list of tuples

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

What would be the best way to create pandas DataFrame with index from records.
Here is my sample:

```
sales = [('Jones LLC', 150, 200, 50),
     ('Alpha Co', 200, 210, 90),
     ('Blue Inc', 140, 215, 95)]
labels = ['account', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales, columns=labels)
```

I need 'Account' to be an index here (not a column) 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simpliest is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales, columns=labels).set_index('account')
print (df)
           Jan  Feb  Mar
account                 
Jones LLC  150  200   50
Alpha Co   200  210   90
Blue Inc   140  215   95
```

Or select by list comprehensions:

```
labels = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
idx = [x[0] for x in sales]
data = [x[1:] for x in sales]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels, index=idx)
print (df)
           Jan  Feb  Mar
Jones LLC  150  200   50
Alpha Co   200  210   90
Blue Inc   140  215   95
```