# Turn List of Dictionaries or Tuples into DataFrame. Actions - Column, Value - rows

Tags: python, pandas, facebook, dictionary, series

I am doing an API call to Facebook and one of the fields is "actions" which creates a dictionary that I would like to break up in to separate DataFrame columns. I have seen a few similar questions using pd.Series() to map them into separate columns or json.normalize(), but those don't exactly do what I'm looking for.

Here's the export before I put it into a dataframe column:

```
[<AdsInsights> {
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "landing_page_view",
            "value": "292"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "13"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save",
            "value": "6"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "874"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "393"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "96"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "96"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_activate_app",
            "value": "5"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_app_install",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_add_to_cart",
            "value": "75"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "add_to_wishlist",
            "value": "14"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_purchase",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_search",
            "value": "12"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_view_content",
            "value": "15"
        }
    ]
```

I then put it into a DF, but the column becomes actions and it fits all of this data into a single row and then repeats it for each item. I am having trouble breaking the action_type into the column header and the value into the row. I get multiple rows of these sets of data when I create the DF.

when I make the dataframe it looks like this:

```
    df[ad] df[actions]
0   ad1     [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value':...
1   ad2     [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value':...
2   ad3     [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value':...
```

I am hoping to get:

```
    df[ad] df[landing_page_view] df[comment] ...etc
0   ad1     292                      13
1   ad2     100                      8 
2   ad3     80                       9
```

I was trying to pick out the specific ones I wanted to make columns, but this does not work:

```
df = all of the raw data from the API call
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
actions = df['actions']
def setcolumn(dict, key): 

    if dict.has_key(key): 
        df['key'] = 'value' 
    else: 
        print ("Not present")

setcolumn(actions, 'landing_page_view')
```

but this says that series object has no attribute has_key.

any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I edited your API result slightly because I'm not sure what the tag at the beginning is for.

The solution is a simple pandas method called from_records(), which converts a list to a dataframe. Here are some reference links:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html
- https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html
- [How to create pandas DataFrame with index from the list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563707/how-to-create-pandas-dataframe-with-index-from-t)

```py
import pandas as pd

# facebook API result as dictionary ... I removed the '<AdsInsights> ' at the beginning
list_facebook_api = {
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "landing_page_view",
            "value": "292"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "13"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save",
            "value": "6"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "874"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "393"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "96"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "96"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_activate_app",
            "value": "5"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_app_install",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_add_to_cart",
            "value": "75"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "add_to_wishlist",
            "value": "14"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_purchase",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_search",
            "value": "12"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_view_content",
            "value": "15"
        }
    ]
}

# create a dataframe from the list inside the dictionary
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html
# https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563707/how-to-create-pandas-dataframe-with-index-from-the-list-of-tuples
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_facebook_api['actions'])

print(df.shape)

# print(df)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, the tag at the beginning is the name of the class I believe. I have to run a class to get the data and that is how it exports. Anyway, when I try your code, the kernel dies for some reason. Also, since I get one of these lists per row inside of the actions column, is there anyway to instead do it as columns? So landing page view would be the column header, then 292 would be the first value and all the other landing page values for the other rows would be listed under it. Does that make sense and is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: Also, when I set the data export to a variable, the variable is considered a cursor. One more thing - there are many other columns being exported with this data, just as an FYI.

Comment: Here is a stack overflow article on how to remove column headers.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688022/removing-header-column-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Hello @pk2019 - I am not sure how that is relevant to this topic. Thank you